# Scraping eliteprospects.com in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the first table with 100 rows on this webpage:
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2018-2019?sort=ppg

I couldn't find a CSS to scrape the entire table at once, so I'm scraping each column separately and then trying to combine all the columns into one dataframe or tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


# Player----------------------------------------------------------------
url <- read_html("https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2018-2019?sort=ppg")

# Player column
player <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .player") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

player <- player[-1]

# Clean player column
player_df <- data.frame(player) %>% 
  mutate(player = as.character(player)) %>% 
  # Filter out empty values (those that have nchar of 1)
  filter(nchar(player) > 0)


# Team----------------------------------------------------------------
team <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .team") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

team_df <- data.frame(team) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  mutate(team = as.character(team))

team_df <- team_df %>% 
  filter(nchar(team) > 0)
# Number of Rows for Teams exceed 100 because some players played on several different teams throughout season


# Games Played-----------------------------------------------------------
gp <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .gp") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

gp_df <- data.frame(games_played = gp) %>% 
  slice(-1) 

gp_df <- gp_df %>% 
  mutate(games_played = as.character(games_played)) %>% 
  filter(nchar(games_played) > 0)
# Number of Rows for Games played exceed 100 because some players played on several different teams throughout season


# Goals-----------------------------------------------------------
goals <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .g") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

goals_df <- data.frame(goals) %>% 
  slice(-1)

goals_df <- goals_df %>% 
  mutate(goals = as.character(goals)) %>% 
  filter(nchar(goals) > 0)


# Assists-----------------------------------------------------------
assists <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .a") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

assists_df <- data.frame(assists) %>% 
  slice(-1)

assists_df <- assists_df %>% 
  mutate(assists = as.character(assists)) %>% 
  filter(nchar(assists) > 0)


# Total Points-----------------------------------------------------------
total_points <- url %>% 
  html_nodes("#skater-stats .tp") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim()

total_points_df <- data.frame(total_points) %>% 
  slice(-1)

total_points_df <- total_points_df %>% 
  mutate(total_points = as.character(total_points)) %>% 
  filter(nchar(total_points) > 0)
```

The problem I face is I have 100 rows of player data inside `player_df`, but 120 rows of their stats since some players played on multiple teams.
For example, Brendan Furry (LW) played on two teams.

How would I remove the stats for the individual teams and only look at `totals` for those players who've played on multiple teams in a reproducible manner? I'd like to perform the same function on multiple years, so I'd like to create a function!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just scrape the table at once and then just filter out rows without a player name in them:

```
url <- read_html("https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/2018-2019?sort=ppg")

tab <- html_table(html_node(url,xpath="/html/body/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/table"))

tab <- tab %>% filter(Player != "")

head(tab,17)

    #                  Player                    Team GP  G  A TP  PPG PIM +/-
1   1       Alex Turcotte (C)          USNTDP Juniors 16 12 22 34 2.13  14  27
2   2         Jack Hughes (C)          USNTDP Juniors 24 12 36 48 2.00   4  17
3   3        Bobby Brink (RW)   Sioux City Musketeers 43 35 33 68 1.58  22  23
4   4      Matthew Boldy (LW)          USNTDP Juniors 28 17 26 43 1.54  16  14
5   5     Trevor Zegras (C/W)          USNTDP Juniors 27 14 26 40 1.48  34  18
6   6    Cole Caufield (C/RW)          USNTDP Juniors 28 29 12 41 1.46  23  19
7   7     Martin Pospisil (C)   Sioux City Musketeers 44 16 47 63 1.43 118  13
8   8       Ronnie Attard (D)          Tri-City Storm 48 30 34 64 1.33  66  46
9   9      Nick Abruzzese (F)           Chicago Steel 62 29 51 80 1.29  20  -1
10 10       Brett Murray (LW)     Youngstown Phantoms 62 41 35 76 1.23  35  13
11 11            Cam York (D)          USNTDP Juniors 28  7 26 33 1.18  12  40
12 12    Matias Maccelli (LW) Dubuque Fighting Saints 62 31 41 72 1.16  42   8
13 13  Mikael Hakkarainen (C)    Muskegon Lumberjacks 42 19 28 47 1.12  22  24
14 14     Michael Gildon (LW)          USNTDP Juniors 26 13 16 29 1.12  28  24
15 15 Robert Mastrosimone (C)           Chicago Steel 54 31 29 60 1.11  28   5
16 16       Ben Meyers (C/LW)             Fargo Force 59 33 32 65 1.10  26  11
17 17      Brendan Furry (LW)                  totals 52 21 36 57 1.10  20  12
```

Comment: Thank you X 100 million